# How to calculate $56!!\bmod29$ using Wilson's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to calculate $2\cdot4\cdot6 \cdots56\bmod29$.

I can write $2\cdot4\cdot 6\cdots56$ as $56!!$. Also, since 29 is a prime, I can use Wilson's theorem, which gives
$$28!\equiv-1\bmod29$$
Where do I go from here? I'm guessing the key is to write $56!!$ as a product of $28!$ and something else, but I'm struggling to find a way to do that.

Comment: That's not $(2n)!$, though

Comment: How so? What I see is this:  $(2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \dotsm 56) = ((2\cdot 1)(2 \cdot 2)(2\cdot 3) \dotsm (2 \cdot 28)) = (2n)!$ for $n \in \{1,2,3, \dots, 28\}$.

Comment: @SBS, if $n=28$, then $(2n)!=56!=56\cdot55\cdot54\cdot53\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1$, not $56\cdot54\cdot52\cdots6\cdot4\cdot2$.

Comment: Oh, right. I guess $(2n)!$ is not the correct way to write it. I didn't know double factorial !! existed as a term before I saw it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have,  $2\cdot 4 \space \cdot \space ...\space\cdot \space 56=(2\cdot1)\cdot(2\cdot2)\cdot\space...\space\cdot(2\cdot28)=2^{28}\cdot28!$

Now, $2^{28}\equiv 1 \pmod{29}$ (Fermat's Theorem)
and

$28!\equiv -1 \pmod{29}$ (Wilson's Theorem)

$\therefore 2^{28}\cdot28! \equiv -1 \pmod {29} $

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots56&\equiv2^{28}(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots28)\mod29\\
&\equiv2^{28}\cdot28!\mod29\\
&\equiv1\cdot-1\mod29\\
&\equiv-1\mod29
\end{align}$$
where $2^{28}\equiv1\bmod29$ because of Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Since $2$ is relatively prime to $29$, we have $\{2,4,6,\ldots,56\}\equiv\{1,2,3,\ldots,28\}$ mod $29$, hence $2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots56\equiv1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots28=28!\equiv-1$ mod $29$, using Wilson's theorem for the final congruence.